# Adding a list value to a map key object and clearing the list object for other values. dart

Tags: flutter, list, dart, dictionary

Am having an empty list which am using to hold objects after which am adding the objects to a new key in a map, which is working fine. My problem comes in when I now clear the list, this operation also clears the already added values in the map object. While am supposed to set the list empty to hold other values.

```
 List<Time> _myTimeSlots = [];
 Map<String, dynamic> selectedValues = {};

onSelected (Time item, index, isSelected) {
        if (isSelected) {
          _myTimeSlots.add(item); 
          
        } else {
          _myTimeSlots.remove(item);
          
        }
      },

  void onSave(BuildContext context,
      {required String day}){
            Map<String, dynamic> mapVal = {day: _myTimeSlots};
            selectedValues.add(mapVal);
            _myTimeSlots.clear() //===> *problem comes in here*

}
```

The first function **onSelected** am calling it after multiple selection of Time objects of a particular day the **onSave**function am calling it after completing selection now to add entries to the final Map of days and time selections.
**NOTE** Each day has its own list of time in the map object.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: the problem am facing is when i clear my list the values related to that list in the already mapped object also disappears